# i am runing my react native app they give me issue. but the build is created when they are run on emulator they give me issue

Tags: android, react-native, native

i am running my native app in android the build is created successfully when i run on emulator they give me the following issue and I don't know how to resolve it but the build is created  they give me this issue :

[image]

how i resolve this issue ?